# Removing a validator with jQuery

Tags: jquery, validation, unobtrusive-javascript

So I've added a validator dynamically to my page with the following code:

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool('zipcode', 'validate_zipcode');
```

Is there a way to dynamically remove it? Something like:

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.removeBool('zipcode', 'validate_zipcode');
```

I've searched Google for something like this but can't find any reference to a remove method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nothing built in, but you can do it via the jQuery validate API

```
$('#zipcode').rules('remove', 'validate_zipcode');
```

Comment: Is there also a way to add/remove methods on the fly (similar to rules)? I've got a big pile of custom methods I'd love to swap in/out based on user input and would like to reference them like a rule... but it doesn't seem to be working. :S